# Why is DataTable serializable?

Tags: c#, serialization

So here's a simple test case:

```
[Serializable]
class Base
{

}

[Serializable]
class Derived : Base
{

}

BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, new Derived());
```

Nothing special here. If you remove either of the 'Serializable' tags, then `BinaryFormatter` yells at you because the items aren't serializable. In theory then, serializing a `DataTable` shouldn't work either because the base class for DataTable -  'MarshalByValueComponent`- isn't marked as serializeable either ('typeof(MarshalByValueComponent).IsSerializable` returns 'false'). So why does BinaryFormatter ignore this but not other non-serializable types? (Or why isn't `MarshalByValueComponent` marked as serializeable to begin with?)

Comment: DataTable *is* marked Serializable.

Comment: Sure, but as I mentioned, if you take the `Serializable` tag off of the the `Base` class above, the `BinaryFormatter` will yell at you because the base class isn't serializable. DataTable's **base** isn't serializable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DataSet` class is defined as follows:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class DataSet : MarshalByValueComponent, IListSource, 
    IXmlSerializable, ISupportInitializeNotification, ISupportInitialize, ISerializable
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

As you can see there is an implementation of the `ISerializable` interface. This interface allows an object to control its own serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. The reason I'm running into this problem is that I've built my own serializer (otherwise I would have never noticed this). So that just means I need to handle `ISerializable` myself.

Comment: If a class needs to control its serialization process, it can implement the ISerializable interface