# How to resolve a null reference exception in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        dt = CType(Session("buyitems"), DataTable)

        If (dt Is Nothing) Then
            Label5.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString()
        Else
            Label5.Text = "0"
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DataList1_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemCommand

        Dim dlist As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList)
        Response.Redirect("AddToCart.aspx?id=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "&quantity=" + dlist.SelectedItem.ToString)
    End Sub
```

I get the exception of `System.NullreferenceException` as "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object:

[image: Exception Details]

Comment: At what line of code is this occuring at? I don't have your ``DataTable`` so I can't tell.

Comment: If dt is nothing, then you access it. You need to switch the brancheso

Comment: The following may be helpful: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v=vs.100)), [Session-State Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178586(v=vs.100)), [Type.IsPrimitive Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=net-6.0), and [Why is DataTable serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347675/why-is-datatable-serializable)

Comment: While you've provided code, you haven't provided a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide sufficient code and/or information that one can use to replicate the issue that you're experiencing.

Comment: Do the is nothing test on session, and then shove into DT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `DataTabl`e stored in the `Session` variable `buyitems` then do not create a `New` one when you declare the local variable.

I think you just reversed assignments in the `If` statement.

It seems that there is not a `DataTable` in the `Session` variable.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = CType(Session("buyitems"), DataTable)
    If dt Is Nothing Then
        Label5.Text = "0"
    Else
        Label5.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If (dt Is Nothing) Then
        Label5.Text = "0"
    Else
        Label5.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString()
    End If
```

This code should solve the issue.